# how many peripherals can be connected to arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I'm doing a project in which I have to constantly monitor the acceleration, gyroscope and heart pulse rate and based on that I have to send location info to particular numbers. Apart from this, I have to send the pulse rate & location info to Google firebase.

Components required:

1. Arduino Uno
2. GPS Module
3. GSM Module
4. Accelerometer/Gyroscope sensor
5. ESP8266 01 WIFI Module
6. Pulse Oximeter sensor

I'm new to Arduino environment. I don't know if I can use all these peripherals simultaneously. Can you please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you don't know that you should probably start with something much much simpler. this would depend on the interfaces of those modules. there will be a way to put all that together. but you will likely fail to do so if you don't start with the basics. one step at a time. also note that this is a programming community. your hardware feasability question is rather off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Arduino Uno has

- 2(SDK,scl) for I2C
- 1 spi,
- 1 UART

most of the above module supports I2C. you can connect multiple slaves to the single master.
you can make Arduino as a master and others as slave